# Other ways to solve an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am dealing with the ODE $\left(3 x^2 y^2+8 e^{4y}\right) y'(x)+2 x y^3+2=0$. I note that it is an exact function thus can be easily solved, the answer is $x^2 y^3+2 x+2 e^{4 y}=c$, where $c$ is a constant. But I am wondering is there any other ways to solve it?